# Unknown function "logout_path" even though symfony security-core is installed

Tags: php, symfony, twig

I got the message

> Did you forget to run "composer require symfony/security-core"? Unknown function "is_granted" in "...".

when calling template-code

```
{% if is_granted(constant('Rights::RGT_TOUR_ADD')) %}...{% endif %}
```

I am using symfony v5.3.7, symfony/security-core and symfony/twig-bridge are both v5.3.7. twig itself is v3.3.2 (just updated the whole stuff). All packages are installed in the "good way" of "symfony composer require..."

There is a bunch of extensions in /vendor/symfony/twig-bridge/Extension and most of them are loaded, but not the SecurityExtension (even though available).

Of course I don't want to hard-code a solution, due to the fact that it would be done in /vendor which is in .gitignore ;)

I already tried forced reinstalling of the package... No change.

Just in case this info is needed... PHP is v7.4.15 x64

Comment: How did you install the packages? Did you also enable the bundles properly? Flex will automatically do this for you, but if you're not using Flex, you need to enable the bundles manually

Comment: Are you using the actual Symfony framework?  How exactly did you create your app?

Comment: Flex is installed (1.15.4) and the packages work well within symfony... Just the extension is missing (the security-http is missing, too. So logout_path isn't working in twig).
Everything is up to date, I am using the latest version.

Answer (score 0):

Security bundle doesn't have `logout_path`.
You need controller action with the path having that name:

```
<?php
namespace App\Controller;

use Symfony\Bundle\FrameworkBundle\Controller\AbstractController;
use Symfony\Component\Routing\Annotation\Route;


class SecurityController extends AbstractController
{
    /**
     * @Route("/logout", name="logout_path")
     */
    public function logout()
    {
        throw new \LogicException('This method can be blank - it will be intercepted by the logout key on your firewall.');
    }
}
```

As for `is_granted` check if `symfony/security-bundle` is installed, enabled in `config/bundles.php`, and configured properly in `config/packages/security.yaml`.